# Getting entity in embedded collection of forms

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms, symfony4

In my edit form I need to get the entity object in embedded form. This is my main edit form:

```
class OrderCollectionsEditType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('sampleCollections', CollectionType::class, [
                'entry_type' => SampleCollectionType::class,
                'allow_add' => true,
                'allow_delete' => true,
                'by_reference' => false
            ])
        ;
    }
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Order::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

and the embedded one:

```
class SampleCollectionType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $sampleCollection = $builder->getData();
        $builder
            ->add('methods', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => Method::class,
                'multiple' => true,
            ])
            {...}
        ;
    }
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => SampleCollection::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

The form created in controller:

```
$form = $this->createForm(OrderCollectionsEditType::class, $order);
```

And the problem is that the `$sampleCollection` returns NULL, but the form is properly filled by the values. Is there any other way to get the entity object?

Comment: did you try 'choice_label' ?

Comment: @ThomasCOUMES No, I need entity object to set/modify 'data' option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, what's suggested in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55023671/17726418) (`$options['data']`) doesn't work with CollectionType, there's no 'data' index.

We can use `PRE_SET_DATA` form event and then get the entity object in listener function:

```
class SampleCollectionType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, function (FormEvent $event) {
                $sampleCollection = $event->getData();

                $form = $event->getForm();
                $form->add('methods', EntityType::class, [
                    'class' => Method::class,
                    'multiple' => true,
                ]);
            })
        ;
    }
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => SampleCollection::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The object is passed to the form in the `$options['data]` property.
Instead of `$sampleCollection = $builder->getData();` get it by `$sampleCollection = $options['data];`