# How to getData() on a collectionType field - Symfony 4

Tags: symfony

I have a collectionType (Equipements) on a Symfony 4 ORM form (intervention).
For example, this equipement field :

```
<input type="file" id="intervention_equipements_0_photoGraffiti" name="intervention[equipements][0][photoGraffiti]">
```

I try to get the data of this field with :

```
$fileToTransfer = $form['intervention_equipements_0_photoGraffiti']->getData();
```

or

```
$fileToTransfer = $form['intervention[equipements][0][photoGraffiti]']->getData();
```

I have the error Child "intervention[equipements][0][photoGraffiti]" does not exist.

Here is my intervention Type :

```
$builder          
    ->add('idInstallation',         EntityType::class, [
        'class' => Installation::class,
        'choice_label' => 'numeroInstallation',
        'required' => false,
    ])

    ->add('equipements', CollectionType::class, array(
        'entry_type' => EquipementInterventionType::class,
        'entry_options' => array('label' => false),
    ))
```

And the equipement entity:

```
        $builder   
            ->add('nom',                    TextType::class, array(
                'error_bubbling' => true,
                'required' => false,
                'disabled' => true
            ))    
            ->add('numero',                 TextType::class, array(
                'error_bubbling' => true,
                'required' => false,
                'disabled' => true
            ))        
            ->add('etatEquipement',         ChoiceType::class, array(
                'choices' => $choices_controle,
                'expanded' => false,
                'multiple' => false,
                'required' => false,
                'error_bubbling' => true,
            ))
            ->add('photoEquipement',        FileType::class, array(
                'error_bubbling' => true,
                'required' => false,
                'disabled' => false,
                'data_class' => null
            ))
            ->add('graffiti',               CheckboxType::class, array(
                'required' => false,
                'error_bubbling' => true,
            ))
            ->add('photoGraffiti',          FileType::class, array(
                'error_bubbling' => true,
                'required' => false,
                'disabled' => false,
                'data_class' => null
            ))
...
```

How can I fix this, please ?

Answer (score 0):

Directly use `$form->getData()`. This will return the array with all your form datas that you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

in your form controller

`$equipements = $intervention->getEquipement();`

will return the array of collections then

```
foreach ($equipements as $equipement) {
    $fileToTransfer = $equipement->getPhotoGraffiti()
}
```

Hope you have getter and setter in your entity class

Answer (score 0):

Try this from this genius answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/55029206/4277724

```
        $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, function (FormEvent $event) {
          $equipement = $event->getData(); 
          $form = $event->getForm();
          $form
            ->add('nom', TextType::class, array(
            'error_bubbling' => true,
            'required' => false,
            'disabled' => true
            ))    
          ->add('numero', TextType::class, array(
            'error_bubbling' => true,
            'required' => false,
            'disabled' => true
            ))        
          ->add('etatEquipement', ChoiceType::class, array(
            'choices' => $choices_controle,
            'expanded' => false,
            'multiple' => false,
            'required' => false,
            'error_bubbling' => true,
            ))
          ->add('photoEquipement', FileType::class, array(
            'error_bubbling' => true,
            'required' => false,
            'disabled' => false,
            'data_class' => null
            ))
          ->add('graffiti', CheckboxType::class, array(
            'required' => false,
            'error_bubbling' => true,
            ))
          ->add('photoGraffiti', FileType::class, array(
            'error_bubbling' => true,
            'required' => false,
            'disabled' => false,
            'data_class' => null
            ))
        })
```